# Django Rest Framework: retrieve object or create object

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In my API I'm trying to build endpoints where dataobjects are retrieved if they exists and created if they don't exists.

**Question:** How can I create this functionality in a single view using DjangoRestFramework's generic views?

What I'm looking for is basically a `RetriveCreateAPIView`, but it does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using the mixins classes:

```
from rest_framework import generics, mixins

class MasterDataView(generics.GenericAPIView, mixins.CreateModelMixin, mixins.RetrieveModelMixin):
     queryset = SomeModel.objects.all()
     serializer_class = SomeSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)
```